# Can't connect to Folding@home server

Tags: networking, folding-at-home

I'm trying to run Folding@home on a Linux box. After configuration, I get the following output:

```
[17:33:20] Work directory not found. Creating...
[17:33:20] Could not open work queue, generating new queue...
[17:33:20] - Preparing to get new work unit...
[17:33:20] + Attempting to get work packet
[17:33:20] - Connecting to assignment server
[17:33:20] - Couldn't send HTTP request to server
[17:33:20] + Could not connect to Assignment Server
```

In other words, it can't connect to the Folding@home server. My box is connected to the Internet and doesn't have any unusual proxy settings; I can use curl just fine, for instance. Yet Folding@home has consistently refused to connect to any server. I've tried this several times over the last couple of days. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*(I posted this question initially. Apologies for using StackOverflow rather than SuperUser—now I reaize the error of my ways.)*

This turned out to be a temporary problem. I tried the same steps again a couple of days later, and it connected to the Folding@home server just fine. Evidently, I had exceptionally bad luck on my first several tries.

Comment: Contact team@stackoverflow.com about getting the question linked to your SuperUser account